# AWS API Gateway custom domain name results in {"message":"Not Found"}

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I tried to create a HTTP API through API Gateway.
This API generated a URL e.g. `https://{api-id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/`

This endpoint works as intended.

After this; I created a custom domain name and under "Api Mappings", I added this newly created API, set the stage the `$default` and left `Path (Optional)` as blank. This generated another endpoint (which is supposed to be added as an A record in Route53). When I try to hit this new endpoint; I get `{"message":"Not Found"}`. This "connection" between the custom domain endpoint and the working api gateway endpoint doesn't seem to work. Any pointers on how to fix this?

Other Information:

- I own the custom domain
- Adding a custom domain required uploading a SSL certificate (I had a valid one and I uploaded it - verified and all good)
- The API is a basic HTTP API which refers to a Cloudfront URL. This endpoint is fully functional and working as expected.
- Endpoint Type: Regional
- No multiple "Stages" for API/Routes - only a `$default` one

Comment: Did you add a DNS record that points to that API Gateway?

Comment: Yes, I did add the DNS record through Route53. It was autosuggested in the Route53 Hosted Zone section.